# Error al subir app bundle en PlayConsole. No se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones. android:export

Tags: android, ionic

Hola recibo el siguiente mensaje al publicar una app en play store:

Has subido un APK o Android App Bundle que tiene una actividad, un alias de actividad, un servicio o un receptor de emisión con filtro de intents, pero sin establecer la propiedad android:exported. Este archivo no se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones posteriores. Consulta developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

Este es mi codigo. Ya no se que hacer despues de 3 dias seguidos intentando solucionarlo. Necesito vuestra ayuda. gracias.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:name="es.lesventsdegrasse.app.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
</application>

<!-- Permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Camera, Photos, input file -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Geolocation API -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<!-- Network API -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Navigator.getUserMedia -->
<!-- Video -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!-- Audio -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero sigo sin poder subir la aplicación, muestro los cambios. <intent-filter android:exported="true"> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> <intent-filter android:exported="true"> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" /> </intent-filter> No se que me falta?

Answer (score 0):

Debes de asegurar que todos los elementos en tu AndroidManifest.xml que hagan uso de `intent-filter` deben tener definido:

```
android:exported="true"
```

---

> **android:exported** Este elemento establece si los componentes de otras aplicaciones pueden iniciar la actividad: Si es "true",
> cualquier app puede acceder a la actividad y se puede iniciar con su
> nombre de clase exacto.

Comment: Por lo que se ve en el xml lo tiene configurado.

Comment: Debe ser android:exported="true"